# How to save an array of custom struct to NSUserDefault with swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I have an custom struct called 'News' that I want to append into the array to NSUserDefault. But it's showing error "Type 'News' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'".

I don't want to change the 'News' struct to a class since it's being used for other code already. Is there anyway that I can change NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("savedNewsArray") type to [News]?

```
var savedNews = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("savedNewsArray")
var addSavedNews = savedNews as? [News]
addSavedNews.append(News(id: "00", title: newsTitle, source: source, imageURL: imageURL, url: url))
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(addSavedNews, forKey: "savedNewsArray")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Here is the 'News' struct.

```
public struct News {
    public var id: String
    public var title: String
    public var source: String?
    public var imageURL: String?
    public var date: NSDate?
    public var url: String

    init(id: String, title: String, source: String, imageURL: String, url: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.source = source
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.url = url
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this article](http://swiftandpainless.com/nscoding-and-swift-structs/)

Comment: Take a look at NSValue API.

Answer (score 14):

NSUserDefaults can only save a very small set of types: `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray` containing only these types, or `NSDictionary` containing only these types. So your best bet is to encode your struct using an NSKeyedUnarchiver, which required a value that conforms to NSCoding. You could make your type conform to this, but I think it's cleaner to hide that from your users and simply have a private class for the internal representation, like this:

```
struct Foo {
    var a : String
    var b : String?
}

extension Foo {
    init?(data: NSData) {
        if let coding = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? Encoding {
            a = coding.a as String
            b = coding.b as String?
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func encode() -> NSData {
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(Encoding(self))
    }

    private class Encoding: NSObject, NSCoding {
        let a : NSString
        let b : NSString?

        init(_ foo: Foo) {
            a = foo.a
            b = foo.b
        }

        @objc required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            if let a = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("a") as? NSString {
                self.a = a
            } else {
                return nil
            }
            b = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("b") as? NSString
        }

        @objc func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
            aCoder.encodeObject(a, forKey: "a")
            aCoder.encodeObject(b, forKey: "b")
        }

    }
}
```

Then to save your array you can simply map `.encode` over your array:

```
let fooArray = [ Foo(a: "a", b: "b"), Foo(a: "c", b: nil) ]
let encoded = fooArray.map { $0.encode() }
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(encoded, forKey: "my-key")
```

and to get it back you can simply pass the `NSData` to the init:

```
let dataArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("my-key") as! [NSData]
let savedFoo = dataArray.map { Foo(data: $0)! }
```

Answer (score 3):

Following is the flow that I have follow

1. Make your struct object
2. Convert struct  to Json object (I will give you file
       link to convert struct to JsonObject and jsonString -> https://github.com/vijayvir/SwiftApi/blob/master/StructureToJson/StructToJson.swift )  import this file in your project :-)
3. Append that value to array
4. If you want to save in user default I prefer you to make class object of array as follow ,(as you can access from any where )
5. save your array in user default as follow

***Struct to save***

> ```
> struct CardDetails : StructJSONSerializable {
> var emailId :String
>
> var accountNo : String
>
> var expDate : String
>
> var cvc : String
>
> var isCurrrent : Bool = false      
>
>
> init(card : Dictionary<String, Any>  )
> {
>     emailId =  card["emailId"]! as! String
>
>     accountNo =  card["accountNo"]! as! String
>
>     expDate  =  card["expDate"]! as! String
>
>     cvc =  card["cvc"]! as! String
>
>     isCurrrent = card["isCurrrent"]! as! Bool
>
> }
>
>  }
> ```

**Save Array to  User Default**

> ```
>   class var  cards : [AnyObject] {
>     get
>         {
>             if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"cardss") != nil)
>             {
>
>             if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "cardss") as? Data
>             {
>                 let unarc = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data)
>
>                 let newBlog = unarc.decodeObject(forKey: "root")
>
>
>
>                 return newBlog as! [AnyObject]
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 return []
>             }
>
>           }
>             else
>             {
>             return []
>             }
>
>         }
>
>     set
>     {
>         //print(type(of: newValue) , newValue)
>
>         let archiveData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newValue)
>
>           let ud = UserDefaults.standard
>           ud.set(  archiveData  ,forKey: "cardss")
>           ud.synchronize()
>     }
>
> }
> ```

**How to save Struct element  to array**
 Here convert you struct object to json Object

> ```
>      let  firstCard = CardDetails(emailId: "asdf",
>                                  accountNo: "dada",
>                                  expDate: "nvn",
>                                  cvc: "e464w",
>                                  isCurrrent: true)
>
>       CardsViewController.cards.append(firstCard.toJsonObect())
> ```

**How to access object from array**
 Here convert you  json Object object to Struct

> ```
> let sameCardIs = CardDetails(card:  CardsViewController.cards.last
> as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
>
>
>
>     print ("Element Function " , sameCardIs )
> ```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

**WORKING IN SWIFT 3**

Following a similar approach to ahruss, I ended up implementing in the following way:

```
struct MyObject {
    var foo : String
    var bar : String?
}

extension MyObject {
    init?(data: NSData) {
        if let coding = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data) as? Encoding {
            foo = coding.foo as String
            bar = coding.bar as String?
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func encode() -> NSData {
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: Encoding(self)) as NSData
    }

    private class Encoding: NSObject, NSCoding {
        let foo : NSString
        let bar : NSString?

        init(_ myObject: MyObject) {
            foo = myObject.foo
            bar = myObject.bar
        }

        @objc required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            if let foo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "foo") as? NSString {
                self.foo = foo
            } else {
                return nil
            }
            bar = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "bar") as? NSString
        }

        @objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
            aCoder.encode(foo, forKey: "foo")
            aCoder.encode(bar, forKey: "bar")
        }

    }
}
```

Oh, and to use it just type the following:

```
let myObject = MyObject(foo: "foo", bar: "bar")
UserDefaults.standard.set(myObject.encode(), forKey: "test")
```

To fetch it,

```
let objectData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "test") as? Data?
guard let storedObject = objectData else {
    return
}
let fetchedObject: MyObject = MyObject(data: storedObject as NSData)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the above answers worked for me.  I finally found this post: https://cocoacasts.com/ud-5-how-to-store-a-custom-object-in-user-defaults-in-swift.

This explains simply how to do it using JSON encoding.  It worked exactly as described in the post.