# use NSUserDefaults with array of struct type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, nsuserdefaults

I have problems to figure out how to save my string of type "RiskEntry" with NSUserDefaults. I already went through some other posts, but somehow I still did not manage to solve this particular issue.

Let me explain what the code from below does right now: I get some data from my class CustomCell in the following code snippet. Here I first check with an "identifier" which array to update with the new array value "consequences".

It all works fine and the updated array is stored in riskEntry.
However, I cannot work out how to store this with NSUserDefaults now. When I try it with e.g. `riskItemDefaults.set(riskEntry, forKey: "riskItem")` I get an exception error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

**SWIFT3** (I removed all code not relevant for this question)

```
class: RiskPlan: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellUpdaterDelegate {

 var riskEntry = [RiskEntry]()
 var riskItemDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

// ------ start of delegate function (receiving from CustomCell) ---------
      func transferData(consequencesTranferred: String, identifier: String) {
        if let index = riskEntry.index(where: {$0.title as String == identifier}) {
            riskEntry[index].consequences = consequencesTranferred
    } else {
        print ("nothing")
    }

// save with NSUserDefaults
        riskItemDefaults.set(riskEntry, forKey: "riskItem")
  }
}
```

This is my struct:

```
public struct RiskEntry {
    let title: String
    var consequences: String
}
```

my Custom Cell

```
// ---------------- delegate to transfer entered data to VC -----------------
protocol CustomCellUpdaterDelegate {
    func transferData(consequencesTranferred: String, identifier: String)
}

// ---------------- start of class CellCustomized -----------------
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    var delegate: CustomCellUpdaterDelegate?

    // text fields, text views and picker views
    @IBOutlet weak var riskTitle: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var consequences: UITextView!

    // ---------------- listener for text view to save input in string when editing is finished -----------------
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.tag == 1 {
            textConsequences = consequences.text
            nameIdentifier = riskTitle.text
            delegate?.transferData(consequencesTranferred: self.textConsequences, identifier: nameIdentifier)
        } else {
            print ("nothing")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: my console output is: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` while my AppDelegate.swift class is selected for `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406457/how-to-save-an-array-of-custom-struct-to-nsuserdefault-with-swift?rq=1

Comment: This solution did it! I had to convert it to swift 3 though and modify it to suit my use case. i will post it as an answer, in case it helps someone else in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you can't save your custom array in NSUserDefaults. To do that you should change them to NSData then save it in NSUserDefaults
Here is the code I used in my project it's in swift 2 syntax and I don't think it's going be hard to convert it to swift 3

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(yourObject);
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "yourKey")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

and to the get part use this combination

```
if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourKey") as? NSData {
    let myItem = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? yourType
}
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

Saving objects in `UserDefaults` have very specific restrictions:

> [set(_:forKey:) reference:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414067-set)
>
> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.

You need to serialize your model, either using NSCoding or as an alternative using JSON, to map to a supported value by `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

The closest type to a Swift struct that UserDefaults supports might be an NSDictionary.  You could copy the struct elements into an Objective C NSDictionary object before saving the data.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to program a solution based on @ahruss ([How to save an array of custom struct to NSUserDefault with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406457/how-to-save-an-array-of-custom-struct-to-nsuserdefault-with-swift?rq=1)). However, I modified it for swift 3 and it also shows how to implement this solution in a UITableView. I hope it can help someone in the future:

1. Add the extension from below to your structure (adjust it to your own variables)
2. Save the required array item like this:

   let encoded = riskEntry.map { $0.encode() }
   riskItemDefaults.set(encoded, forKey: "consequences")
   riskItemDefaults.synchronize()
3. Load your item like this

   let dataArray = riskItemDefaults.object(forKey: "consequences") as! [NSData]
   let savedFoo = dataArray.map { RiskEntry(data: $0)! }
4. If you'd like to show the saved array item in your cells, proceed this way:

   cell.consequences.text = savedFoo[indexPath.row].consequences as String

Here is the complete code, modified for **Swift3**

structure

```
// ---------------- structure for table row content -----------------
struct RiskEntry {
    let title: String
    var consequences: String
}
```

extension

```
  extension RiskEntry {
        init?(data: NSData) {
            if let coding = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data) as? Encoding {
                title = coding.title as String
                consequences = (coding.consequences as String?)!
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }

        func encode() -> NSData {
            return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: Encoding(self)) as NSData
        }

        private class Encoding: NSObject, NSCoding {
            let title : NSString
            let consequences : NSString?


            init(_ RiskEntry: RiskEntry) {
                title = RiskEntry.title as NSString
                consequences = RiskEntry.consequences as NSString?
            }

            public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
                if let title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as? NSString {
                    self.title = title
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
                consequences = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "consequences") as? NSString
            }

            public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
                aCoder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
                aCoder.encode(consequences, forKey: "consequences")
            }

        }
    }
```