# How to save user data with struct - Swift

Tags: swift

I have a struct called `trip`:

```
struct trip {
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var elements: [elementType] = []
}
```

*`elementType` is a type declared in protocol.*

Then I've declared an array called `trips`:

```
var trips: [trip] = []
```

The problem is that I have to save `trips` array to be able to show items after closing the app. First of all, I tried to use NSUserDefaults but it can save only few types and `Any` (type of struct) isn't one of them.

How can I save and restore this array?

Answer (score 0):

You can only save `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, and `NSDictionary` types in `NSUserDefaults`.

So you can add a init method inside the struct so that the data being created can be encoded and then stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

Follow the answer to this question: [How to save struct to NSUserDefaults in Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674302/how-to-save-struct-to-nsuserdefaults-in-swift-2-0)